# com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Error when saving credential

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

This error occurs when signing in to my app using Firebase.ui.auth and google sign-in, unable to get data from firestore too because of the error.

```
2019-06-22 22:16:57.237 6793-6793/meter.meterE/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Error when saving credential.
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.SmartLockHandler$1.onComplete(SmartLockHandler.java:98)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 6: Passphrase required.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.zaf(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaj.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zaa(Unknown Source:172)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source:131)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BaseImplementation$ApiMethodImpl.setResult(Unknown Source:36)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzo.zzc(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzv.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzd.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

Comment: share your code at **SmartLockHandler.java:98**

Comment: here is the link https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/viewmodel/smartlock/SmartLockHandler.java @AyodeleKayode

Comment: have you created a project on firebase.com ?

Comment: @AyodeleKayode yes working on the project from 30 days, this error occured yesterday suddenly, don't know why

Comment: are you getting the error at    `task.getException())));` ?

Comment: yeah, the log shows that.

Comment: try changing getException to getMessage

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your passwords on Google account are protected with a passphrase. I think this should be a `ResolvableApiException`, but they did not put an effort into coding resolution handling for the situation. So you have to live with the fact that users with passphrases will not be able to benefit from Smart Lock. For testing, you can reset your passphrase. See instructions: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139